# Rails AJAX PUT method not working and Heroku error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, heroku

I have an `Article` model and a `articles` controller.
The `index` action:

```
def index
 @article=Article.find(id: params[:id])
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
 end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<a href="" id="find">Find Article</a>
<div id="article">
  <%= render @article %>
</div>  

$('#find').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
   type: "PUT",
   data: {id: id},
   url: "/index"
 });
});
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$('#article').update("<%=escape_javascript(render(@article))%>");
```

**_article.html.erb**

```
<p><%= @article.name %></p>
```

**routes.rb**

```
get '/index', to: "articles#index"
put '/index', to: "articles#index"
```

But nothing is showing in the partial. The p tag is empty. There is no error in the logs.
Let's say if no records matched the query, then it should give `nil` error.

**Also** on heroku when I go to the `index` page, it throws error (everything works fine locally)

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):

So what is happening here? How does ajax in rails work? what I can get from the above error is that when the `index` action is called (when I visit it) it tries to det the `@article` variable, which is `nil` and at the same time it renders the `_article.html.erb` partial too .Definately `@article` is nil first time.The query wil be made only after I click on the link and make a ajax request.How does rails know that this is a ajax request?

What wrong am I doing?

Thanks for help.

**UPDATE**

**Now, tried few things, even when I don't put anything in the `index.js.erb` the `@articles` variables is rendered properly in the console.**

Comment: your click function is not closed properly.

Comment: @hawk that was a typo. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try

```
Article.find(params[:id])
```

If not, check if there is an article object with the id you are passing

Comment: yup. there exists an article with that id. I'm just explicitly passing the hash params to be sure what I'm doing. Bet'n the query is returned correctly in the console and when I view the html there the `_article.html.erb` template is rendered properly. It just doesn't show up on the browser page. and doesn't work at all on Heroku.

Comment: @whoIsCraig try <%= render "article", :locals => {:article => @article} %> and <%= article.name %>

Comment: now I'm getting the same error as I get in heroku. `undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Bet'n can u tell me why heroku is giving that error? can u answer the last part of the question? How ajax in rails work? and why is it happening that everything is working in console and not outside?